# Regex Match - Only if 4 characters long and does not contain a specific word

Tags: regex

I am currently attempting to create a program that matches words that are a specific length, or more, that do not contain a specific word.

Currently I have the Regex : `\S{4,}(?!\w*apple\w*)`

When used on the test : `I love these delicious applestoo`

There Regex will still match 'applestoo', which I do not want.

I can see that this is a logic error, but I do not understand how else to format this Regex. If you have a solution pelase do tell me, thank you in advance.

Edit:

This code now works for my example: `(?!\w*apple\w*)\b\S{4,}\b` However, when using this new example it will still fail: `'logigng some testing data  _______-----apple-###zx'`

I have attempted to ammend this through using: `(?!\w*(apple|_)\w*)\b\S{4,}\b` but this does not seem to be working.

Comment: `(?!\w*apple\w*)\b\S{4,}\b`

Comment: Maybe `r'\b(?!\w*apple)\w{4,}'` will do?

Comment: @depperm This works for the first example, though not for one I have jsut tested. My apoligies for not being as thorough as I should of been.

Comment: what is the expected grouping/ouput of the last input?

Comment: @depperm The output should be, matches in square brackets: [logigng] [some] [testing] [data]  _______-----apple-###zx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `\b(?![^\W_]*apple)[^\W_]{4,}\b` ([explained at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2SVFRx/1))

This uses `[^\W_]` as the character matcher, which will match any character that is not a non-word character and not an underscore. This leaves the non-underscore word characters, making it similar to `[[:alnum:]]` (assuming [POSIX named character class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) support) or `[0-9A-Za-z]` … if you just want letters, consider `[[:alpha:]]` or, for just ASCII letters, `[A-Za-z]`.

The negative lookahead, which follows the `\b` word boundary marker for performance reasons, states that we can't have "apple" follow zero or more of these characters (regardless of what may follow it). We then ask to match four or more of these characters and then another word boundary marker.

In the following command-line demonstration, I've used `grep -Po` to demonstrate this. `-P` causes `grep` to use its PCRE interpreter (from libpcre) and `-o` causes it to show only matches, with each match on its own line:

```sh
$ echo 'logigng some testing data  _______-----apple-###zx' \
    |grep -Po '\b(?![^\W_]*apple)[^\W_]{4,}\b'
logigng
some
testing
data
$
```

Comment: `[^\W]` is far from equal to `[A-Za-z0-9]`. Umlauts, diacretics etc are also included. In a unicode implementation, the difference is even larger.

Comment: @Kaii – that depends on your locale and locale settings, but you're right and that's why I used the double negative rather than spelling out the individual characters. I don't know the implementation in question, so I don't know if `[[:alpha:]]` is acceptable.

Comment: Actually it depends even more on the implementation used, engines handle unicode differently. I thought it should be mentioned at least.

Comment: "`\W` is a shorthand for `[^\w]`" "In most flavors that support Unicode, `\w` includes many characters from other scripts."  https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: @Kali – The whole point was to exclude underscore. `[^\W_]` is _not_ equivalent to `\w` because only one of those two allows underscores. Calling `\W` "shorthand" for `[^\w]` precludes the ability to make a double-negative the way I have here. Your other comments are correct but technicalities. (I didn't want to mention them without knowing the regex implementation since, as you noted, different implementations use locales differently.)

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I was stupid last night. Deleted that wrong comment.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression to match a word with 4 characters only is "\b\w{4}\b".
The "\b" is a word boundary that matches the position between a word character (as defined by the \w character class) and a non-word character.
The "\w{4}" matches any four word characters, and the final "\b" is a word boundary again.

```js
    let word = "word";
    let pattern = /\b\w{4}\b/;
    
    if (pattern.test(word)) {
        console.log("match");
    } else {
        console.log("no match");
    }
```